# Which would be correct: "outputs" or "puts out"?

Tags: word-choice, phrasal-verbs, definite-articles, programming

Which word should I use in the following context? Is *the* required before *data*?

> Any algorithm first reads data, processes (the) data and finally [outputs|puts out] the processed data.

Comment: Unless the algorithm is for a porn site, I would avoid saying it "puts out"

Comment: "Puts out" would be the [awful German](http://how-to-learn-any-language.com/e/languages/german/the-awful-german-language.html) way of doing things.

Comment: Can the verb *outputt* be used in golf?  If so, be careful not to write *outputted* for the past tense of the verb *output* in this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any algorithm first reads the data, processes the data and finally outputs the processed data.

Comment: yes: "puts out" is for use when referring to an action such as "he puts out the garbage" (yes, I know - 'takes' would make slightly more sense in that sentence). Output is the result of an action, not the action itself.

Comment: @warren: [Flanders & Swann](http://www.nyanko.pwp.blueyonder.co.uk/fas/hat_mader.html) illustrated various uses of *put out* succinctly: *And he said as he hastened to put out the cat, The wine, his cigar and the lamps: "Have some Madeira, m'Dear!"*

Answer (score 2):

Outputs would be the most common term. But "generates" is also used, especially for results that are not necessarily meant to be human readable, such as compiler output, and other intermediate or low level data.